# How to generate a series using While loop

Tags: python

```
n = int(input("Enter n: "))
sum = 0
i = 1
while i <= n:
    sum = sum +1
    i = i+1
print("The sum is" , sum)
```

I tried the above code but didn't got my answer.
The question is to generate a series that is: 1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22 using while loop.

Comment: What is the user input for?

Comment: Shouldn't you be adding 3 instead of 1 each iteration?

Comment: You want output plus by 3 but you plus it by 1 ? I'm not sure what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate series you need to do two things:

1. Put the print inside the loop to output accumulator variable's value every iteration
2. Add 3 to sum every iteration and not 1 since it's the difference between series members

   ```
    n = int(input("Enter n: ")) # n=8 should work
    sum = 1
    i = 1
    while i <= n:
        print(str(sum)+",")
        sum = sum +3
        i = i+1
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I see two errors:

- You should add `i` to sum,not `1` (this assumes you are interested in the sum as implied by the code)
- You should be incrementing `i` by `3` not by `1`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want this:

```
i = 1
while i <= 22:
   print(i)
   i += 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
n = int(input("Enter n: "))
count = 0
i = 1
sum = 0
while count <= n-1:
    print(i)
    sum += i
    i += 3
    count += 1
print("Sum is", sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to increase the count by three every time with `i += 3`.

```
def createList():

    user_input = input()

    i = 1
    list_of_vals = []
    while i < int(user_input): # The max value:
        list_of_vals.append(i)
        i += 3

    return list_of_vals

print (createList())
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
n = int(input("Enter n: "))
series_sum = 0
i = 1
series = []
add = 3

while i <= n:
    series.append(i)
    series_sum = series_sum + i
    i = i + add    
   
print("series: ", series)   
print("The sum is" , series_sum)
```

This would get you a series (and sum of elements) with the last element less than `n`, starting from `i = 1` and increment `add = 3`